# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre [[ ]] y [ ] en R?

Tags: r

Si usamos el data.frame de prueba "iris" de R y escribimos las siguientes sentencias:

```
> class(iris["Species"])
[1] "data.frame"
> class(iris[["Species"]])
[1] "factor"
```

¿Por qué R nos devuelve un objeto diferente en cada sentencia?

También existe diferencia con este ejemplo:

```
> class(iris[ , "Species"])
[1] "factor"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los dos son los operadores básicos de `R` para obtener subconjuntos de una estructura de datos. Funcionan de manera muy similar. Como son equivalentes en muchos casos tendemos a pensar que son iguales, pero no es así. Las diferencias se hacen visibles cuando estamos trabajando con listas, es decir, con objetos de la clase `list`.

Cuando trabajamos con listas `[ ]` nos regresa **siempre** otra lista más pequeña(* ver más abajo) con el/los elementos que seleccionamos. En cambio `[[ ]]` regresa solamente los elementos que seleccionamos en el tipo en el que están dentro de la lista. Por ejemplo, si es un vector, va a regresarnos un vector y no un vector "envuelto" en una lista.

Hay una analogía interesante en el libro [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html): si la lista `x` es un tren y los elementos dentro de `x` son los vagones entonces `x[vagones]` me regresa un tren con los vagones seleccionados, mientras `x[[vagones]]` me regresa solo los vagones (no un tren más pequeño).

Para el ejemplo que presentas en tu pregunta ten en cuenta que `iris` es un data.frame, pero que en sentido estricto los data.frame son un tipo especial de listas. Para mantener las cosas simples voy a empezar con lista "pura". La lista `x` no está nombrada, voy a acceder directamente por lo número de índice. El resultado es el mismo que si estuvieras accediendo por nombres.

```
x <- list(c(1, 2), "a", list("a", "b"))
```

La lista `x` tiene tres elementos: un vector numérico, uno de caracteres y una lista. Veamos como podemos hacer subsets con los diferentes operadores y que resultados obtenemos.

## Uso simple: índices enteros positivos

```
#Me regresa el elemento contenedor: una lista. 
x[1] 

#Me regresa el elemento contenido: un vector numérico.

x[[1]]
```

## Subconjuntos negativos

Este caso es interesante porque `[[ ]]` no funciona.

```
#Me regresa una lista sin el elemento 2. 
#Atención: se reciclan las posiciones, lo que antes era 3 ahora será 2. 

x[-2] 

#Me regresa un error: R no sabe que tipo de elemento debe regresarme. 

x[[-2]]
```

## Una lista dentro de una lista

Uso `str` para hacer visible la estructura del objeto.

```
# Me regresa la lista que está en la posición 3 dentro una lista.
str(x[3])

# Me regresa la lista que está en la posición 3 sin más. 
str(x[[3]])
```

## Tratar de acceder a dos dimensiones

```
# Me da un error: número incorrecto de dimensiones. 
# Las listas "puras" son unidimensionales y anidadas.

x[1, 1]
```

## ¿Qué pasa con los data.frame?

Comenté que todos los data.frame son un tipo especial de lista. ¿Qué tienen de especiales?

1. Todos los elementos de esa lista tiene exactamente el mismo largo. Cfr. la lista `x` en la que los elementos tiene diferentes largos.
2. Como todos tienen el mismo largo es una estructura de datos que podemos representar de manera rectangular, la analogía es con una matriz.

Por estas particularidades los data.frame permiten dos vías diferentes para hacer subconjuntos: como listas que son y como matrices que pretenden ser.

Es confuso porque usas los mismos operadores, el cambio se da cuando usas la `,` e indicas implícitamente que está accediendo a una estructura de datos bidimensional (con filas y columnas). Por eso en tu último ejemplo aunque usas `[]` y no corchetes dobles obtienes un elemento atómico y no una lista: al ver la coma que indica multidimensionalidad (filas y columnas) `R` usa las reglas de subconjuntos de las matrices, no de las listas. Eso lo hace porque los data.frame tienen sus propios métodos para el uso de `[`.

Para mayor confusión en R el "comodín" para seleccionar todo es un espacio en blanco. Aunque no es necesario es buena práctica dejar el espacio antes de la coma, porque visualmente es fácil confundir `iris[1]` con `iris[,1]` y para `R` estás haciendo cosas totalmente diferentes.

Dentro de los data.frame puedes cambiar este comportamiento usando el argumento `drop = FALSE`. En ese caso no se descarta el contenedor y te regresa un data.frame con una sola columna, en lugar de la columna como vector.

```
class(iris[ , "Species", drop = FALSE])
```

Para aún más confusión si le pides más de una columna indicando un vector de nombres o números de índice te regresará un data.frame, aunque explícitamente le pidas que "suelte" la estructura contenedora:

```
class(iris[ , c("Species", "Petal.Width"), drop = TRUE])
```

## ¿Cuál usar?

Depende de lo que queremos. Cuando estamos trabajando con listas "puras" (no data.frame) casi siempre queremos acceder al elemento que está dentro de la lista sin el contenedor, entonces vamos a usar `[[ ]]`. Al recibir el elemento de manera atómica (no dentro de una lista) podemos hacer operaciones directamente: por ejemplo, sumar los vectores como en el caso de `x[[1]] + x[[1]]`.

Cuando estamos trabajando con data.frame la cosa cambia. A veces podríamos querer obtener un data.frame, otras veces un vector atómico, algunas veces se antoja hacer subconjuntos tratándolo como una lista, otras veces tratándolo como una matiz. Esto da flexibilidad, pero al mismo tiempo facilita cometer errores y generar una estructura de datos que no es la que necesitamos.

Personalmente este es uno de los motivos por los que empecé a usar la librería `dplyr` para trabajar con data.frame. Tienes unas reglas claras y sus operadores de subconjuntos (`select` y `filter`) **siempre** regresan un data.frame. Nunca te toma por sorpresa un vector cuando esperabas un df ni te tienes que acordar del argumento `drop = FALSE`. Tiene su costo: para hacer operaciones sobre las columnas hay usar las funciones `mutate` y `summarise`, algo que se puede evitar fácilmente en `R` base accediendo de manera directa a los elementos del data.frame con `[[]]`. Pero creo que la carga cognitiva es menor: te acostumbras a esperar y recibir siempre un data.frame.

(*) Para mantener las cosas simples asumo que el subconjunto es para obtener una parte más pequeña de una estructura de datos. Obviamente no es así siempre: puedes usar a los operadores repitiendo elementos y en ese caso obtienes más datos de los que tenías antes o usarlos y obtener exactamente los mismos datos.